# changing form behavior on submit based on radio button selection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radio-button

I'm using Rails 3.1.0.rc5. I want to have a form with a pair of radio buttons, `enable` and `disable`, and a field to enter an integer (`expire_after_days`, the number of days until ticket expiration), with a hidden field for the fixed parameter `subdomain_name`. I'd like to be able to use the same simple form to create, edit, or delete a record, depending on which radio button is checked.

So if `enable` is checked, with no record found for the `subdomain_name`, a record would be created on form submission.

If `enable` is checked, and a record is found, the existing record should be updated on form submission.

And if `disable` is checked, the record should be deleted on form submission.

Is this a reasonable thing to do? If so, what tips do you have for how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not ideal nor restful to have all 3 actions (create, update, destroy) cramped up in just one controller method, but if you wish to continue on this dirty route here's what you could do:

```
def my_dirty_method
  if params[:enable].present?
    if params[:subdomain_name].present?
      # Edit subdomain
    else
      # Create subdomain
    end
  end
  if params[:disable].present?
    # Delete subdomain
  end
```

Comment: [EDIT: Nevermind, thought this was a batch update situation]

Hmm, how would you solve it in an ideal, restful way? AJAX calls for every action (or, worse yet, force a page refresh for each action)? Imagine something like a case where you have email aliases associated with an account, and want to determine which ones receive notifications.

Comment: I'd like to present the user with more or less the same visual every time they vist the page, and I'd like to always have it at the same URL. I see your point about my current plan being unrestful, though. Can you suggest a more restful solution?

Comment: I've given up the idea of having the final URL be the same, and instead have a URL that decides whether to redirect to the `new` record page or the `edit` record page. There are now separate controller actions for create, update, and destroy. It also means I no longer use the radio buttons, but I really appreciate your input, @Thiago.